# What is the recommended way of start and supervise daemons on Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, monitoring, daemon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ensure a process is always running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/881/ensure-a-process-is-always-running)

At the moment I use a quick and dirty `nohup ... &` to start application and database servers. E.g.

```
su - foo -c "nohup php-cgi -b 8888 &"
```

This approach has obvious disadvantages of not starting my service at boot, not restarting the service and/or notifying me if it crashes, not automatically starting dependent daemons, having to `ps` to look for PID to kill etc.

I found `upstart` but it seems to break the `rc.d` so I have to reconfigure all system-wide daemons such as `sshd`, `syslog-ng` etc to use it.

Is there a non-intrusive alternative to `upstart` that works well with arch linux, coexists with existing `rc.d` scripts, supports running daemons under specific users and respawns them if they die? A support for dependencies and notifications on a respawn is a plus but is not required.

Of course I can write a rather simple shell script myself and plug it into `rc.d`, but are there any de facto standard well-tested solutions besides `rc.d` which doesn't provide respawning?

UPD: I found `monit`. Is it any good, and are there any better solutions?