# How do I use daemonize to always keep my tomcat process running?

Tags: java, daemon

I was researching how to keep a background process running and I came across daemonize. This answer says that I can use daemonize to ensure a process is always running: "[Ensure a process is always running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/881/ensure-a-process-is-always-running/918#918)". I went thru the man page: http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/daemonize.html .

It only closes stdin, stdout, stderr, changing work directory to root, etc. It's doing all the things that a good background process should do.

The only thing I found related to restarting was -p pidfile for outputting the process id and -l lockfile for making sure only one process is started.

Comment: It's doing all of the things [that a good process **should not** do](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html#DoNotBackgroundise) and it is a perpetuation of [the dæmonization fallacy](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/bsd-service-command.html#Inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the tomcat package of your distribution, you can use [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) and define your own unit file such as:

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Read the tutorial [How To Install Apache Tomcat 8 on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7) for full details.